# Python regex - extract name before phone number

Tags: python, regex

I have a raw text object with the following:

```
Bryar Pitts
5543 Aliquet St.
Fort Dodge GA 20783
(717) 450-4729
Rahim Henderson
5037 Diam Rd.
Daly City Ohio 90255
(453) 391-4650
Sheila Mcintosh
P.O. Box 360 4407 Et Rd.
Santa Monica FL 30309
(746) 679-2470
```

I could retrieve all the phone numbers with the function below.

```
data=re.findall(r'\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}',text)
```

Next thing is how do I go about extracting the names Bryar Pitts, Rahim Henderson and Sheila Mcintosh? Do I have to specify new lines and objects before a phone number is reached?

Thanks.

Comment: You might try an alternation `|` with a character class without digits for the names [`^\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}|(?:[A-Za-z]+ )*[A-Za-z]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/BGlcOg/1)

Comment: ```^[A-Za-z ]+$``` This regex will take all the strings that start with alphabets and have a space character, you can try it. As in the sample text, I can see the names are on one line and all other lines contain some special character or a number.

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve every first out of 4 lines? the first line is the name and the fourth line is the phone number.

Comment: is this a fixed format or some of your data has some entry missing

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct approach. But might help.

```
import re
s = """Bryar Pitts
5543 Aliquet St.
Fort Dodge GA 20783
(717) 450-4729
Rahim Henderson
5037 Diam Rd.
Daly City Ohio 90255
(453) 391-4650"""

print(re.findall("[a-zA-Z\s]+(?=\s+\d{4,4})", s, flags=re.MULTILINE)[::2])
#or
print(re.findall("[a-zA-Z\s]+(?=\n)", s, flags=re.MULTILINE))
```

**Output:**

```
['Bryar Pitts', '\nRahim Henderson']
['Bryar Pitts', '\nRahim Henderson']
```

Comment: HI, your one is working there. But what if the second row has an address with no 4 digit number? I was wondering is there a way to identify the phone number and then scale back to the name.

Comment: is this working for you `print(re.findall("[a-zA-Z\s]+(?=\n)", s, flags=re.MULTILINE))` ?

Answer (score 0):

You might use capturing groups if you want to match the name and the phonenumber in the 1st and 4th row (Assuming that this order does not change)

[`([a-zA-Z ]+)\n(?:.*\n){2}(\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4})`](https://regex101.com/r/gk1zNq/1)

**Details**

- `([a-zA-Z ]+)\n` Capture in group 1 lowercase or uppercase  or a whitespace using a character class followed by a newline
- `(?:.*\n){2}` Match 2 whole lines
- `(\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4})` Capture in group 2 your phonenumber regex

[Demo](http://rextester.com/FAS67100)

Answer (score -1):

https://regexper.com
I find this helpful when working with RegEx.

I think it depends on whether you work on your text char by char, then you might have to do that.
If you go line by line, the name lines should not have any numbers in them, so you could work with that, maybe.

It also depends on the data that you work with and how sure you are that it is free of errors.
If it is always 4 lines per person, you could check line by line and use RegEx to also make sure it matches your expectation so that if you find a number in a name you throw an exception or at least log it somewhere.

Hope this helps, good luck!